# EF - Not able to call the stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, ora-06550

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_NAME'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Not able to call the stored procedure which returns the `OUT SYS_REFCURSOR` using the EF-6

NOTE: I'm able to call a stored procedure which returns an INT.

Comment: MORE ERROR LOG - {"ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_NAME'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 8:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"}

Comment: at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleI

Comment: Can you edit your post with your stacktrace?